# Is "until mine is on tight" an idiom?

Tags: idioms

I was studying English, so I downloaded a comprehension reading test and I found a phrase which I can't understand:

> Seat belts save lives and that's a fact. That's why I don't drive anywhere **until mine is on tight**.

I think that it's an idiom because I don't find word definitions that help me understand the phrase.

Comment: A seatbelt is something you put on, and you can make it tight.

Comment: 'on tight' is not usually hyphenated.

Comment: @AldairRev - Maybe what's hanging you up is "Mine is on."  Compare this with: *A: Please put on your jacket.  B: I already have it on.* What B meant was, "I am already wearing my jacket.

Comment: "on tightly" would be clearer but less idiomatic; a comma after *on* would increase both parts.

Comment: "Put your seat belts on, kids". i.e. fasten them.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's not an idiom. Each word means exactly what it says.

*Mine* means 'my one', referring back to the seat belt.

*On tight* means exactly what it says - fitted securely. So

> I will not drive anywhere until my seat belt is fitted securely.

Comment: also note that the implied object of the preposition 'on' is [me], and 'tight' is adverbial, so a paraphrase would be "until my seat belt is on me tightly".

Comment: I'd say that "on" means "worn, donned," not "attached." Just like how "I have a hat on" indicates that the hat is worn, not that the hat is attached.

Comment: 'on' can have very many meanings. I would not disagree with 'worn' here.

Comment: I think it's worth being explicit that using "tight" as an adverb here is colloquial. I think it would be clearer to change it to "... until mine is on tightly", or perhaps even "... until mine is on, tightly".

Comment: Colloquial but extremely common.

Comment: Nitpicking a little, but 'mine' is not a contraction of 'my one'. It's the original Old English word (originally 'min'), from which 'my' is derived. The German 'mein' has the same Proto-Germanic root.

Comment: A small issue could be that the first sentence says seat belts, When mine is on, that is my seat belt, of course, not my seat belts.

Answer (score 9):

" I don't drive anywhere until mine is on tight."

If you built this sentence bit by bit, it would go like this:

1. I don't drive anywhere until my belt is on.
2. I don't drive anywhere until my belt is on tight. [the belt is tight, snugly fit]
3. I don't drive anywhere until mine is on tight.

So each word (after until) means this:

- Until: while the following doesn't occur.
- Mine: reffers to [my] "seat belt" in the previous sentence.
- Is on: the belt is on = the belt is in place [i.e. the belt is fastened]
- Tight: the belt is fastened tight [i.e. the belt is tight and safety is assured].